# SSAS - Parent-Child Hierarchy with multiple types of Hierarchy

Tags: many-to-many, ssas, grouping, parent-child, hierarchy

My data is as follows:

**Employee Table:**

```
EmployeeID        EmployeeName          Departement
   A             Michael Jackson            D1
   B             Amy Winehouse              D3
   C             Brad Pitt                  D3
   D             Name1                      D2
   E             Name2                      D2
   F             Name3                      D1
```

**Departement Table:**

```
DepartementID   DepartementParentID  DepartementName   DepCountry
D1                      D1                Name1           USA
D2                      D1                Name2           USA
D3                      D2                Name3           USA
D2                      D2                Name1           Tunisia
D1                      D2                Name2           Tunisia
D3                      D1                Name3           Tunisia
```

**Fact Table:**

```
EmployeeID      Value
    A            10
    B            50
    C            30
    D            40
    E            120
    F            600
```

Now as you can see in the Departement table, there are two types of hierarchy: Tunisia and USA. 
The root member in Tunisia is D2 and while in USA it's D1.

What I want to have in my SSAS Cube (Excel) is something like the "Desired Result" table from the image in the link "Results" below.

This is a perfect case for a Many to Many relationship like explained in the the next link. http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/articles/57811.aspx

I have tried this, the only issue is that my employee is not grouped under the hierarchy, I'm getting a result like the "Real Result" table from the link "Results"

**Link:**
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQjkL.png)

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working? Or if not, any other ideas to get my desired result?

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.